# How do I use pathlib to create files named for range of dates?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I can print a range of filenames with the below code but I need to write empty files instead of printing. I know that pathlib.Path.touch and accomplish this but . . . do I need to define a method for the touch?

```
import datetime
import pathlib

for i in range(0, 180):
    print((datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(i)).strftime("%Y%m%d" + ".exml"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to define a method. Try this:

```
import datetime
import pathlib

for i in range(0, 180):
    fname = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(i)).strftime("%Y%m%d" + ".exml")
    print((fname))
    pathlib.Path(fname).touch()
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks a million.

Comment: Why does it need to be print((fname))? What does the extra set of parens do?

Comment: The extra pair of parens are just that, extra. I didn't delete them when I moved the equation out of the print statement. Good catch.